# How do i take a disk image of Ubuntu 16.04 on a NAS

Tags: backup, nas

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a VM running on a Windows 10 host.
As a complete newcomer to Linux, never mind Ubuntu, I am completely baffled by the setting up of a simple backup of the disk to a share on a network attached Drobo. I have looked at 'bacula' and the complexities and apparent insistence of using Tape astound me.

I want to set up a backup which can be started manually to take an image of the Ubuntu disk and store it on a share in my Drobo. I also want to test that I can recover the image to the main disk of the Ubuntu system.

The backup should be an Incremental or Differential type. I note that there is apparently no known software that does Differential backups.

Any answer appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have great portion of information about backups:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: Thanks, it was from that site that I learned that there is software that does differential backups. The other information is not very helpful. I need to know, that unlike 'bacula', any possible software is KNOWN to support backup over a local area network and doesn't demand a 'TAPE DRIVE'  which I do not have nor want to have.